# How to make absolute point move with correct position when relative image resize in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have an a relative div contains image and points with the points created by click to the image. The image set absolute with full content of parent div. The points absolute with top and left is {x,y} coordinates get from mouse clicked.
Everything is working fine, but when the window or the image resize, the points are not at correct position.
This is my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/aaaaa-w8t476?file=%2Fsrc%2FYourComponent.jsx%3A41%2C23) what i implemented.

My question is: how can i make the point created at correct position when image or window resize.Many thanks for any help